# Video Controls as Text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to recreate the video controls as such that it appears as text and only appears on hover, exactly the same as the videos hosted in this website: http://www.brownsdesign.com/work/, any idea how. I've got the text, but it is not functioning as a playpause button. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

html:

```
<div class="item chopsticks hamburger shake">

    <video class="noauto" loop="loop" controls="controls" poster="images/27890.jpg" height="auto" width="300">
        <source src="videos/b_cs.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'"></source>
        <img src="images/27890.jpg" alt="" />
    </video>

    <div class="controller" style="display:none;">
        <div class="controlContainer">
            <a class="vidPlay" style="cursor: pointer;">Play</a>
            <a class="vidPause" style="cursor: pointer;">Pause</a>
            <a class="vidStop" style="cursor: pointer;">Stop</a>
        </div> <!-- end .controlContainer -->
    </div> <!-- end .controller -->

</div> <!-- end .item chopsticks hamburger shake -->
```

Comment: my gosh, the website you linked is maybe the least user friendly and usable I've seen in a while. Horizontal scroll. O god why?! (plus I havent seen any video there)

Comment: @MightyPork windows 8 has horizontal scroll, works just fine... its the responsiveness that matters, which this website lacks

Comment: Well, it works with the firefox autoscroll feature (click and drag), but it's just painful to use.

Comment: @OP please make a jsfiddle.net where we can see the issue?

Comment: i didn't use the website i showed in firefox, only in chrome.@MightyPork

Comment: @Banana jsfiddle: < http://jsfiddle.net/Kyj7d/ > this is what i have with the video working. i'm just trying to figure out how to get the text to function as the video controller

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17609859/3406576

Answer (score 0):

So why not use jQuery?

```
$('.item').hover(function() {
    $('.controller').slideDown();
}, function() {
    $('.controller').slideUp();
});
```